# How to enhance prediction accuracy on different machine learning algorithms in ML.Net

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net

I am new to Ml.Net and am currently using version 0.11, more specifically, binary classifiers, in something that I am currently working on. I am at a point now where I have figured it out and can achieve what I need, but I want to be able to refine things and open up my options.

I have questions regarding setting options on stochastic gradient descent, stochastic gradient ascent dual co-ords, and logistic regression algorithms. The prediction accuracy on unseen data for these (without options set) is much worse than that of the Fast Tree algorithm, which has leaves, tree, and min data points in leaves as options, set (e.g. 50% versus 89% accuracy). Like I set options with FastTree, I cannot figure out how to set options for the other ML algorithms (i.e. numTrees, numLeaves etc) , and as it is not a RC yet, there is little to no documentation, neither is there examples that I can find.

I would also like to know 'typical' options that someone might set with these algorithms, so I can gain a baseline and change things from there.

I have figured out the Logistic regression can have an options object composed and passed to it, but I cannot find the same for the others, nor know what is typical for options to pass to the logistic regression algorithm.

I have scoured the net, but come up empty handed.

Appending my pipeline with the following gives good accuracy:

```
.Append(mlContext.BinaryClassification.Trainers.FastTree(numLeaves: 50, numTrees: 50, minDatapointsInLeaves: 20));
```

appending my pipeline with any of these below gives terrible accuracy

```
.Append(mlContext.BinaryClassification.Trainers.LogisticRegression());
            .Append(mlContext.BinaryClassification.Trainers.StochasticGradientDescent());
      .Append(mlContext.BinaryClassification.Trainers.StochasticDualCoordinateAscent());
```

Also, using the Fast Tree with no options gives poor performance, e.g.:

```
.Append(mlContext.BinaryClassification.Trainers.FastTree());
```

I have figured out the optiosn for logistic regression (i.e. below), but do not know what 'typical values' to set / what options to include:

```
 var LogRegOptions = new Microsoft.ML.Trainers.LogisticRegression.Options
 {
    SgdInitializationTolerance = ?,
    InitWtsDiameter = ?,

    ?????
 };
```

I would like to get these algorithms to predict at around the same accuracy as the fast tree with given options (89%), but they all give less than 50% accuracy without options loaded into them.

Thanks ahead people

Comment: What does this have to do with asp.net or linq?

Comment: Apologies, I got a little trigger happy there... I will take them off.